# How to carry out a 5 input 5 output sensitivity analysis?

Tags: sensitivity-analysis

I have a vehicle (truck) model. There are five inputs, which are:

1. Turn Radius
2. Longitudinal slope (going up or down=
3. Cross slope of the road
4. Road friction
5. Cargo weight

By varying each of these inputs in combination with each other I have run thousands of simulations and recorded five outputs:

1. proximity to lane marker ( to check whether the vehicle leaves its own lane)
2. Roll angle ( to check if the vehicle rollover)
3. lateral acceleration
4. Articulation angle
5. wheel slip (to check if the vehicle is skidding)

For each of the outputs i have a range of values for which the vehicle is safe. I need to perform a sensitivity analysis to generate a range of allowed values for the inputs which will always result in safe outputs. How do I go about doing this?